# Two basic questions about topological linear space theory

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

For a topological vector space(tvs), I'd like to know whether

1.there exist a topological vector space V which is a Hausdorff space but does not satisfies the first countable axiom or

2.there exist a topological vector space V which is not a Hausdorff space and does not satisfies the first countable axiom.

I have questioned this problem but one may cannot see this. So I let it be alone and questioned this problem again.

I really find it difficult for me. Help me please. I can't work it out so far.

Please give me two examples about them. Thank you very much.

Comment: For the first question, every weak-star dual of an infinite-dimensional normed linear space is Hausdorff and not metrizable - so not first countable.

Comment: For the second question, as you consider probably only tvs about the real or complex field with standard topology, the only non-Hausdorff tvs is the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\text{ or }\mathbb{C}\}$. This topology is first countable.

Comment: Thank you, about the second question, I really just consider a tvs on the real or complex field K with standard topology. But why the "only" non-Hausdorff tvs is the trivial topology? It is amazing! Is it really right that there does not exist such a tvs that it's non-Hausdorff and it's not the first countable? Could you prove it? Or introduce me some referrences about it.

Comment: Sorry, I messed things up. On $\mathbb{K}^n$ the only non-Hausdorff topology is the trivial topology. I guess - but have never checked that really - that in the infinite dimensional case there are non-Hausdorff tvs.

Comment: Vobo, could you prove it for me, even though its simple condition, e.g. "On the Euclid space the only non-Hausdorff topology is the trivial topology." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimensional topological vector space $X$ consider the vector subspace $V:=\text{closure}(\{0\})$. You have $V = \bigcap \{U | U\text{ neighbourhood of }0\}$. This implies that the subspace topology of $V$ is the trivial topology, as every open set containing $0$ contains $V$.

Let $\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}$ be a vector space basis of $V$ and extend this by $\{b_{m+1},\dots,b_{m+n}\}$ to a basis of X. Now consider the vector space isomorphism $T:X\to V\times X/V$ defined by
$$
T(\sum_{i=1}^{m+n} c_i b_i) = (\sum_{i=1}^m c_ib_i , (\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n} c_ib_i) +V).
$$
$T$ is continuous, as $\pi_V\circ T$ and $\pi_{X/V}\circ T = \pi_{X/V}$ are continuous. $T$ is open, as every open set containing $0$ contains $V$ and every surjective linear map onto a finite dimensional Hausdorff tvs is an open map [$X/V$ is a Hausdorff space, as the zero element $V$ is closed]. So altogether, $X\cong V\times \mathbb{K}^n$ where $V$ carries the trivial topology and $\mathbb{K}^n$ the euclidean topology.

Comment: Thanks, but just tell me that 1.why the subspace topology of V is the trivial topology;2.the isomorphism what you have defined is the product of two component?3.why x/v is a Hausdorff space?4.what did you prove? "X is the same as the trivial topology" or "the same as the trivial topology multiplies the Euclid topology" or "the trivial topology multiplies the trivial topology".

Comment: I tried to clarify the statements, does this answer your questions? I assume that you know that every finite dimensional *Hausdorff* tvs is some euclidean $\mathbb{K}^n$.

Comment: Wa, you are so nice. Your proof is clearly easy to understand,but I'm still puzzled by "T is open". And I have some difficult in why "T is continuous". I know that thm every surjective linear map onto a finite dimensional Hausdorff tvs is an open map, and I can prove this thm.

Comment: I suggest you to digest a general lemma: A map $f$ into a product space $\prod_i X_i$ is continuous, iff all the projections $\pi_i\circ f$ are continuous.

Comment: Oh, good suggestion. But why T is open? I can't link it with your reason.

Comment: Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $X$. You know 1. $V\subseteq U$ and 2. $\pi_{X/V}[U]$ is open in $X/V$. So $T[U] = V\times \pi_{X/V}[U]$ which is an open set in the product space.